intermittent Error of Scope not active in spring batch for processing a file
I am using Springbatch to process files, the uses case is I need to process list of files recieved sequentially, for that I am using MultiResourceItemReader,
Flow is -

I'm getting multiple presigned url in the request from Rest api call.
Then, calling a method runBatchJob in a different thread (runBatchJob is annotated with @Asycn), there I am downloading all the files in the local storage and calling the run method of spring batch.

FYI -

all the reader, writer, processor are custom written not using what spring provides becoz of some limitation.

Issue -
-> The issue is, flow is working fine when I hit the API on odd times, but getting below error on even time. means the flow working when I hit 1st time then error on 2nd time, then again working 3rd time, error on 4th time and so on.
-> in the even flow (when we are getting error), "beforeJob" method of defaultJobExecutionListener executes successfully, the it tries to create the bean of stepConfig but gives below error and execution comes to "afterMethod" of defaultJobExecutionListener and job ends after that.
Please tell me whats wrong in the config.
Also, please tell me, is this the right standard way of using spring batch for file processing, I reffered spring offical doc. to write code in this fashion.
ERROR -
 [Encountered fatal error executing job] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.itemWriterFactory': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
Classes -

Controller -

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class BatchJobController {
    private final JobRunner jobRunner;

    @PostMapping(value = "/startJob", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> startBatchJob(@RequestBody JobRunObj jobRunObj, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Map<String, Object> responseBody = new HashMap<>();
        log.info("Received request to trigger batch job : request body : {}", jobRunObj);
        jobRunner.runBatchJob(jobRunObj);
        responseBody.put("message", "Successfully triggered Batch job");
        return ResponseEntityBuilder.okResponseEntity(responseBody, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}


JobRunner (Component)

@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JobRunner {
    private final JobLauncher simpleJobLauncher;
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;
    private final FileDownloadService fileDownloadService;
    private final Job job;

    @Async("propagateUserContext")
    public void runBatchJob(JobRunObj jobRunObj) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String jobRunId = JobProcessorHelper.generateJobRunId(jobRunObj);
        log.info("Received job request to process with Job Run Id : {} , jobRunObj : {}", jobRunId, Jackson.toJsonString(jobRunObj));

        JobContext jobContext = getJobContext(jobRunObj, jobRunId);
        List<String> localFilePaths = fileDownloadService.downloadFiles(jobRunObj, jobRunId);

        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString(JOB_RUN_ID, jobRunId)
                .addString(TEMP_FILE_PATHS, String.join(",", localFilePaths))
                .addString(BATCH_JOB_CONTEXT, mapper.writeValueAsString(jobContext))
                .addString(BATCH_JOB_RUN_OBJ, mapper.writeValueAsString(jobRunObj))
                .toJobParameters();

        try {
            simpleJobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            log.error("Error starting job with job run Id : {} | {}", jobRunId, exception.getMessage(), exception);
        }
    }
}


JobConfig class -

@Configuration
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchJobConfig {
    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;
    private final PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();

    @Bean Job batchJob(Step stepConfig, DefaultJobExecutionListener defaultJobExecutionListener){
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(stepConfig)
                .listener(defaultJobExecutionListener)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public DefaultJobExecutionListener defaultExecutionListener(@Value("#{jobParameters}") Map<String, String> jobParameters, CustomStepHandlerFactory customStepHandlerFactory) throws JsonProcessingException {
        JobRunEvent jobRunEvent = mapper.readValue(jobParameters.get(BATCH_JOB_RUN_EVENT), JobRunEvent.class);
        return new DefaultJobExecutionListener(jobParameters, customStepHandlerFactory, jobRunEvent, imdHelper, mapper);
    }

    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public Step stepConfig(TItemReader itemReaderFactory, TItemProcessor itemProcessorFactory, List<TItemWriter> itemWriterFactory, @Value("#{jobParameters}") Map<String, String> jobParameters) throws JsonProcessingException {
        JobContext jobContext = mapper.readValue(jobParameters.get(BATCH_JOB_CONTEXT), JobContext.class);
        int chunkSize = fileProcessingConfig.getReader().getChunk();
        MultiResourceItemReader<?> multiResourceItemReader = getMultiResourceItemReader(itemReaderFactory, jobParameters);
        ItemProcessor itemProcessor = itemProcessorFactory;
        ItemWriter<?> compositeItemWriter = getCompositeItemWriter(itemWriterFactory);

        TaskletStep taskletStep = this.stepBuilderFactory.get("fileProcessingStep")
                .chunk(chunkSize)
                .reader(multiResourceItemReader)
                .processor(itemProcessor)
                .writer(compositeItemWriter)
                .build();

        taskletStep.registerStepExecutionListener(new DefaultStepExecutionListener(itemReaderFactory, itemProcessorFactory, itemWriterFactory));

        return taskletStep;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public TItemReader itemReaderFactory(@Value("#{jobParameters}") Map<String, String> jobParameters) throws JsonProcessingException {
        JobContext jobContext = mapper.readValue(jobParameters.get(BATCH_JOB_CONTEXT), JobContext.class);
        StepHandler readerType = jobContext.getType();//dummy, getting from jobContext
        TItemReader reader = null;

        switch (readerType) {
            case CSV_READER:
                reader = new CsvReader();
                break;
            case JSON_FILE_READER:
                reader = new JsonFileReader();
                break;
        }
        return reader;
    }


    private MultiResourceItemReader<?> getMultiResourceItemReader(TItemReader itemReader, Map<String, String> jobParameters) {
        Resource[] resourcesFromPaths = getResourcesFromPaths(jobParameters.get(TEMP_FILE_PATHS));
        MultiResourceItemReader<?> multiResourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
        multiResourceItemReader.setResources(resourcesFromPaths);
        multiResourceItemReader.setDelegate(itemReader);
        return multiResourceItemReader;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public TItemProcessor itemProcessorFactory(@Value("#{jobParameters}") Map<String, String> jobParameters) throws JsonProcessingException {
        JobContext jobContext = mapper.readValue(jobParameters.get(BATCH_JOB_CONTEXT), JobContext.class);
        StepHandler processorType = jobContext.getType();//dummy, getting from jobContext
        TItemProcessor itemProcessor = null;
        switch (processorType) {
            case JSON_TRANSFORMATION:
                itemProcessor = new JsonProcessor();
                break;
        }
        return itemProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public List<TItemWriter> itemWriterFactory(@Value("#{jobParameters}") Map<String, String> jobParameters) throws JsonProcessingException {
        
        JobContext jobContext = mapper.readValue(jobParameters.get(BATCH_JOB_CONTEXT), JobContext.class);
        List<StepHandler> writeTypes = jobContext.getType();//dummy, getting from jobContext
        List<TItemWriter> itemWriterList = new ArrayList<>();
        writeTypes.forEach(writeType -> itemWriterList.add(getItemWriter(writeType))); // by method getItemWriters getting object for writer 
        return itemWriterList;
    }

    private ItemWriter<?> getCompositeItemWriter(List<TItemWriter> itemWriterList) {
        CompositeItemWriter itemWriter = new CompositeItemWriter<>();
        itemWriter.setDelegates(itemWriterList);
        return itemWriter;
    }
}



DefaultStepExecutionContext - Setting execution context the reader, writer, processor which will be lazy injected.

@Slf4j
public class DefaultStepExecutionListener implements StepExecutionListener {
    private TItemReader itemReader;
    private TItemProcessor itemProcessor;
    private List<TItemWriter> itemWriters;

    public DefaultStepExecutionListener(TItemReader itemReader, TItemProcessor itemProcessor, List<TItemWriter> itemWriters) {
        this.itemReader = itemReader;
        this.itemProcessor = itemProcessor;
        this.itemWriters = itemWriters;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        JobExecution jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
        ExecutionContext executionContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();
        try {
            itemReader.setExecutionContext(executionContext);
            itemProcessor.setExecutionContext(executionContext);
            itemWriters.forEach((itemWriter) -> {
                try {
                    itemWriter.setExecutionContext(executionContext);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception occurred while setting executionContext in the Reader : " + e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return null;
    }
}



TItemWriter

public abstract class TItemWriter implements ItemWriter<?> {
    abstract public void setExecutionContext(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws IOException;
}


tried different solution availaible on stackover flow.

added this in application.properties

#spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.batch.job.enabled=false

tried giving taskExecutor() property to step config. by creating new thread pool.


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
